# antipodal map on circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ be $p(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ and $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be an antipodal map, meaning that $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y).$

 Let $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1$ be the path $\alpha(t)=p(2\pi t)$ and $\hat{\beta}:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the lift of $\beta=f \circ \alpha$, meaning that $p\circ \hat{\beta}=\beta=f \circ \alpha$.

 I need to show that there is an integer $n$ such that
$$\hat{\beta}(\frac{1}{2})=\hat{\beta}(0)+(2n+1)\pi.$$
Then, in general, that
$$\hat{\beta}(t)=\hat{\beta}(t-\frac{1}{2})+(2n+1)\pi$$
for all $t \in [\frac{1}{2}],1$.

 If I look at $\beta(0),\beta(\frac{1}{2})$, I get
$$\beta(0)=f\circ \alpha(0)=f(p(0))=f(1,0)$$
and
$$\beta(\frac{1}{2})=f\circ \alpha(\frac{1}{2})=f(p(\pi))=f(-1,0)=-f(1,0).$$
More generally,
$$\beta(t)=f\circ \alpha(t)=f(p(2 \pi t))=f(\cos(2 \pi t),\sin(2 \pi t))$$ and
$$\beta(t-\frac{1}{2})=f\circ \alpha(t-\frac{1}{2})=(\cos(2 \pi t -\pi),\sin(2 \pi t -\pi))=f(-\cos(2 \pi t),-\sin(2 \pi t))=-f(\cos(2 \pi t),\sin(2 \pi t))=-\beta(t).$$
I am not sure how to conclude from here that there is an integer $n$ such that
$$\hat{\beta}(\frac{1}{2})=\hat{\beta}(0)+(2n+1)\pi$$ and
$$\hat{\beta}(t)=\hat{\beta}(t-\frac{1}{2})+(2n+1)\pi.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = \hat\beta(1/2)$ and $b = \hat \beta(0)$. Using $\beta(1/2) = -\beta(0)$ we get $$\begin{align*}
\cos(a) &= -\cos(b)\\
&= \cos(\pi - b) \\
\implies \pi - b &= 2n\pi \pm a\\
\implies b &= (2n+1)\pi \pm a
\end{align*}$$ and
$$\begin{align*}
\sin(a) &= -\sin(b)\\
&= \sin(\pi + b) \\
\implies \pi+b &= n\pi + (-1)^na\\
\implies b &= n\pi + (-1)^{n-1}a\\
\end{align*}$$
Combining the two gives $b = (2n+1)\pi + a$ as desired.